# How can I prove that $\frac{m^2+1}{\left|m+\frac12\right|}$ is a rational number for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: rational-numbers, integers

How can I prove that
$$\frac{m^2+1}{\left|m+\frac12\right|}$$
is a rational number for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$?

I know that the numerator is rational number  but the denominator is always a rational number for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @JohnColeman A common definition of $\mathbb{Q}$ is as the *field of fractions* of $\mathbb{Z}$. Depending on how you define $\mathbb{R}$, it might not make sense to define $\mathbb{Q}$ using the concept 'real number'.

Comment: @JohnColeman You should distinguish between 'could be defined' and 'commonly is defined'. Defining the rationals as the field of fractions of the integers is extremely common. Defining the complex numbers as the algebraic closure of the reals is extremely uncommon (in analysis), and would require one to prove that such as set can be expressed as a vector space over R. Defining the rationals as a subset of the reals is also extremely uncommon. How do you define the reals?

Answer (score 17):

If you mutiply the top and bottom of your fraction by $2$, you get:

$$\frac{m^2+1}{|m+\frac12|} = \frac{2(m^2+1)}{|2m+1|},$$

which is a ratio of two integers, and we don't have to worry about the denominator being $0$, because that's not possible for an integer $m$. In general, to show that the quotient of two rationals is rational, you just need to clear denominators:

$$\frac{a/b}{c/d} = \frac{a/b}{c/d}\cdot\frac{bd}{bd} = \frac{ad}{bc}.$$

Comment: It may also be important to note that $|2m+1|$ is never equal to $0$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Fair enough. Edited, although if we know that the original is defined at all, that's already taken care of, really.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I do appreciate showing that the denominator is non-zero. If the question were "For which $m\in\Bbb Z$ is $\frac{m^2+1}{|m+1|}$ a rational number?" you'd definitely have to do the check.

Answer (score 11):

The quotient of two rationals is always a rational number.

Comment: yeah I know it bur how can I prove that?

Comment: Let $p=a/b$ and $q=c/d$. Simply compute $p/q$ and use the definition of a rational number.

Comment: Except when the other number is zero.

Comment: @KennyLau I decided not to express all the needed assumptions. This is a matter of so-called mathematical culture of OP. I think that 100% precision is not needed here. It is not necessary to recall me that division by zero is impossible,

Comment: @Eii : A rational number is a number of the form $a/b$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers and $b\ne 0.$ A quotient of two rational numbers is therefore something of the form $\dfrac{a/b}{c/d}$ where $a,b,c,d$ are integers and $b$ and $d$ are not $0.$ Arithmetic tells us that $\dfrac{a/b}{c/d} = \dfrac{ac}{bd}$ and $ac$ and $bd$ are integers and $bd\ne 0.$ So that is a rational number. But how do we know that rule of arithmetic is correct---that that is the right way to divide fractions? Maybe that could be a separate question. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy yeah but also c must not be 0 right?

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's not exactly what arithmetic would tell us. :p

Comment: @eli : Yes. Actually $a$ is the only one that could be $0. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, Arithmetic tells us that $\frac{a/b}{c/d}=\frac{ad}{bc}$ ;)

Comment: @Geliormth : oh .... That's what you meant!

Comment: ERRATUM: $$ \frac{a/b}{c/d} = \frac{ad}{bc}. $$

Answer (score 4):

You can either prove the rationals are closed under the four arithmetic operations, or in your specific case you can just demonstrate it.  If $m \gt 0$ your fraction is $\frac {m^2+1}{m+\frac 12}=\frac {2m^2+2}{2m+1}$ and we have displayed two integers you can divide to get your number.  The denominator is never zero because of the $\frac 12$.  The case $m \lt 0$ is similar.

Comment: Except when you are dividing by $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field thus if $k  \in \mathbb{Q},k  \neq 0$ then $k^{-1}=\frac{1}{k} \in \mathbb{Q}$

and that if $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $ab \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Except when $k=0$.

Comment: Yes indeed thank you for point it out...